# Проблема с анимацией

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Нужно что бы при определенном условии выполнялась анимация.
Сделал анимацию для Ellipse, и хочу вызвать в определенном участке кода ее.
Насмотрелся разных примеров на разны ответ-вопрос сайтах. Нашел такой вариант - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755651/call-a-storyboard-declared-in-xaml-from-c-sharp.

Сделал точь точь с примером. Вызывает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это предотвратить ?!
    public partial class Switcher : Window
        {
            public Switcher()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

```
        bool Action = false;
        double   InitPxls = 15;
        double FinitePxls = 420;
        double Movement;
        Point Point;

        private void CircleKnob_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = true;
            Point = Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob);
            Mouse.Capture(CircleKnob);
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Action)
            {
                Movement = Canvas.GetLeft(CircleKnob) + Mouse.GetPosition(CircleKnob).X - Point.X;

                if (Movement > InitPxls && Movement < FinitePxls) {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob,   Movement);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, Movement - 15);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CircleKnob_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Action = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);

            if (Movement < InitPxls + 210)
            {

                this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window_Loaded);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob,   InitPxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, InitPxls - 15);
            }
            else
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleKnob,   FinitePxls);
                Canvas.SetLeft(CircleShadow, FinitePxls - 15);
            }
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("EllipseInite") as Storyboard;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.CircleKnob);
            sb.Begin();
        }
}
```

.XAML:

```
<Canvas>
            <Rectangle x:Name="ToggleSwitch" Width="665" Height="260" Style="{StaticResource BaseButton}"          >
            </Rectangle>
            <Label     x:Name="SwitchLables"                          Style="{StaticResource SwitchLabel}" 
                       Canvas.Left="322" Canvas.Top="88"                                                           >SWITCH</Label>
            <Ellipse   x:Name="CircleShadow" Width="260" Height="260"  Fill="{StaticResource CircleBehind}"
                       Opacity="0.7"
                       MouseMove="CircleKnob_MouseMove"
                       >
            </Ellipse>
            <Ellipse   x:Name="CircleKnob" Width="230" Height="230"  Style="{StaticResource EllipseEffect}"
                       Fill="{StaticResource Circle}" 
                       Canvas.Left="14" Canvas.Top="15"

                       MouseDown="CircleKnob_MouseDown"
                       MouseMove="CircleKnob_MouseMove"
                       MouseUp  ="CircleKnob_MouseUp"   >
                <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="7" Opacity="0.5" Softness="1"             ></DropShadowBitmapEffect>
                </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
            </Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
```

И сама анимация:

```
<!--ANIMATED ELLIPSE TO CORNERS-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseInite">
        <DoubleAnimation To="15" Duration="00:00:4">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="EllipseFinite">
        <DoubleAnimation To="420" Duration="00:00:4" >
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <ElasticEase Oscillations="1" 
                             Springiness="27" 
                             EasingMode="EaseOut">
                </ElasticEase>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

Имеет значение, где лежит `Storyboard`. Например, стили имеют привычку замораживать себя и всё внутри себя, могут замораживаться ресурсы в `App.xaml` и т.п. Разморозить замороженный объект нельзя, можно только склонировать:

```
if (sb.IsSealed)
    sb = sb.Clone();
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как его тогда применить в коде? Просто в условие где [ if (Movement < InitPxls + 210) ] Прописать еще условие как Вы написали?
Я только что так попробовал, могу попередвигать Ellipse и всё, после чего программа останавливается и закрывается =(

Comment: @A.Laketych Предполагается клонировать перед тем, как изменять, то есть перед падающим вызовом `Storyboard.SetTarget`. В логику анимации я не вникал. / Сама по себе программа закрываться не должна. Если она падает, то отладчик должен поймать исключение.